# How do I solve call to undefined function idn_to_ascii() on wamp?

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, php, wamp

I'm currently on windows 64 bits

basically I can't launch a virtual host because I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function idn_to_ascii() in
>   C:\wamp64\www\add_vhost.php on line 347

on my php Error log, I get these lines when launching a virtual host:

```
[15-May-2019 16:22:56 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function idn_to_ascii() in C:\wamp64\www\add_vhost.php on line 347

[15-May-2019 16:22:56 UTC] PHP Stack trace:

[15-May-2019 16:22:56 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp64\www\add_vhost.php:0
```

I tried reinstalling WampServer, and I will try to copy the entire folder from a coworker and see if it works. Is there any solution that don't involve my coworkers?

[This is how I'm creating my virtual host. Other people that work with me do it basically the same way, but only I get the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5FR5.png)

[This is the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw1Wz.png)